# HomeController question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I added a homecontroller to an application using mvc.

I think it should only work when I type localhost/home

However it works even when I just type  localhost

anyone know why?

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("Hello world mvc");
           // return View();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's down to your routing rules in your Global.ascx.cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

You can change `"Home"` to a different controller name or remove this line entirely.

Answer (score 3):

The default route maps to `home/index` so when you don't specify a controller or action, it will go to the `Index` method on the `Home` controller.  If you look in global.asax.cs, you can change how the routing is done, but I wouldn't recommend this until you are more familiar with MVC and how routing works.  You can find an overview of routing at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs.